# C header file #ifndef #include error

Tags: c, header, include, typedef, ifndef

I'm trying to figure out, how to use C headers with #ifndef and #include.
Lets say I have these two header files:

**headerA.h:**

```
#ifndef HEADERA_H
#define HEADERA_H

#include "headerB.h"

typedef int MyInt;
TFoo foo;
... some other structures from headerB.h ...

#endif
```

**headerB.h**

```
#ifndef HEADERB_H
#define HEADERB_H

#include "headerA.h"

typedef struct foo{
    MyInt x;
} TFoo;

#endif
```

**headerA.c**

```
#include "headerA.h"

... some code ...
```

**headerB.c**

```
#include "headerB.h"

... some code ...
```

When compiling headerB.c, it says

```
In file included from headerB.h,
                 from headerB.c:
headerA.h: error: unknown type name ‘MyInt’
```

I think, it's becouse when **headerB.h** is compiling, it defines **HEADERB_H** and then, when **headerA.h** wants to include **headerB.h**, the `#ifndef HEADERA_H` is false = skips including.

What is the best practice here? I just read, that best practice is to do all `#include` directives in header files, but in this situation it looks like a problem.

EDIT: Ok, sorry for misleading you. This is just and example from bigger project with more files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *circular dependency*. Header file `headerA.h` depends on `headerB.h` which depends on `headerA.h` and so on and on.

You need to break that dependency, for example by *not* including `headerB.h` in `headerA.h`. It's not needed (nothing in `headerA.h` needs anything from `headerB.h`).

---

If you have to include `headerB.h` (as stated in your recent edit) then you first should reconsider how you use your header files, and what definition you place where. Perhaps move the definition of `MyInt` to `headerB.h`? Or have more header files, like one for type-aliases (like your `MyInt` which I personally see no use for), one for structures and one for variable declarations?

If that's not possible then you could try by changing the order of definitions and the include, like

```
#ifndef HEADERA_H
#define HEADERA_H

// Define type alias first, and other things needed by headerB.h
typedef int MyInt;

// Then include the header file needing the above definitions
#include "headerB.h"

TFoo foo;
... some other structures from headerB.h ...

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question. So There is no simple solution than remaking HEADER files or breaking best practices and include headerA.h before headerB.h in headerB.c

Comment: @Risinek Circular dependency is bad design. If you include something you derive something from there, there is no reason why the thing you include also needs something from you.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the line

```
#include "headerB.h"
```

from file headerA.h

Comment: thats not solution for my problem, becouse in headerA.h I need other structures and functions from headerA.h. I edited question